# Click event not working on dynamic Id

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, click

I am creating a dynamic table and would like to show a form by clicking on the `<a>` element which has a dynamically created id. The only way I am able to display the form is to set the selector in the click event to the table id (#table 2), but I don't understand why I can't do it with greater specificity.

```
$.each(json, function (index, value) {
    var posttimestamp = value.Post_timestamp;
    var replytimestamp = value.Reply_timestamp;
    var topic = value.Topic;
    var post_txt = value.Post_txt;
    var reply_txt = value.Reply_txt;
    var species = value.Species;
    var postuser = value.Post_User;
    var replyuser = value.Reply_User;
    var medcond = value.MedCondPrimary;
    var breed = value.Breed;

    if (value.Post_timestamp != check) {
        var newpost = 'y';
    } else {
        var oldpost = 'y';
    }


    if (newpost) {
        $('#table2').append('<tr><td   id="posttopic" colspan="2"><a href="forum24.php"           id=' + posttimestamp + '>' + topic + '</a></td><td></td></tr><tr><td id=' + "post" + posttimestamp + '>' + posttimestamp + '</td><td  id=' + "post" + posttimestamp + 'colspan="3">' + post_txt + '</td><td>' + postuser + '</td><td>' + breed + '</td></tr>');
    }

    $('#' + posttimestamp).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.form').show();
    }
```

Comment: How does your markup look? what is `$('#'+ posttimestamp)` can you post a fiddle to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that

`$('#' + posttimestamp).click(function(e) {...})`

to

`$('#' + posttimestamp).live("click", function(e) {...})`

You might have a case where jQuery is trying to bind the click event to your `.append()`-ed table cell that doesn't exist in the DOM yet. Using `.live()` will bind the click event to elements that exist now OR in the future.

The reason why using the table ID works as a selector is that the table definitely already exists in the DOM when you call `.click()`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Based on your answer I did some further research and see that as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. I tried the .on method as well but that did not work. Strange, since the syntax looks pretty much the same as .live.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) :

```
 $('#' + posttimestamp).live("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('div.form').show();
 }
```